# how to update kernel when I can't install kmod?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I have a problem..

I want to update my kernel, but I have a notice when I install the new kernel like this `please install the kmod first`.

so I install `kmod`, but when I install the `kmod`, my terminal say

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kmod is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kmod' has no installation candidate
```

why?? and when I check `dpkg -l kmod` i have this

```
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
in  kmod           <none>         (no description available)
```

can you help me to update my kernel, my friend? I'm newbie ubuntu user.
My kernel *3.5.0-23-generic* ..
Thank You ..

Comment: Given your kernel version, you may be running an EOL version of Ubuntu.

Comment: my kernel version is 3.5.0-23-generic

Comment: what a meaning of an EOL version of Ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release i can't update with this option my bro